# How to check if the letters/chars in a string are all found in a char array

Tags: java, arrays, string, char

How would I check if a string only contains letters from a certain char array

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    static char[] f = {'q','w','e','r','t','y','u','i','o','p'};
    static char[] s = {'a','s','d','f','g','h','j','k','l'};
    static char[] t = {'z','x','c','v','b','n','m'};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int count = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            String str = sc.nextLine();
            if(string only contains letters from array f) count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why dont you use string instead of char array for f, s, t? Then you can using contains method to solve your problem.

Comment: `int count = Stream.generate(sc::nextLine).limit(sc.nextInt()).filter(s -> s.chars().map(new String(f)::indexOf).allMatch(i -> i > -1)).count();`

Comment: @shmosel what? I don't really understand that.

Comment: HINT: two loops, one over the characters in `str` and, inside that one, another over the characters in the array `f`

Comment: @shmosel There must be a more readable way

Comment: @ScaryWombat Undoubtedly.

Comment: @Kuais seven answers - make a choice and accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change code to use regular expression would be the easiest:

```
public class Main {
    private static final String f = "[qwertyuiop]*";
    private static final String s = "[asdfghjkl]*";
    private static final String t = "[zxcvbnm]*";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            String str = sc.nextLine();
            if (str.matches(f)) {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *would be the easiest* - maybe not

Answer (score 2):

Here is my code, maybe it can help you:

```
public static boolean checkIfStringContainsLettersFromArray(String str, char [] arr) {
    String arrString = new String(arr);

    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if(arrString.indexOf(str.charAt(i)) < 0) return false; 
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: `String arrString = new String(arr);`

Comment: Oh yeah, Thanks shmosel! I edited my answer as you suggested

Comment: Depending on the length of the string and the char[] it might be more efficient to create a Hash Set for the whitelist and call contains on that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `containsAll` of a `List`

```
char arr[] = "scarywombat".toCharArray();
List<Character> limit = new ArrayList<Character>();
List<Character> input = new ArrayList<Character>();

for (char c : arr) {
    limit.add (c);
    input.add (c);
}

System.out.println(limit);
System.out.println(input);
System.out.println(limit.containsAll(input));

//add extra char
input.add('Z');
System.out.println(limit);
System.out.println(input);
System.out.println(limit.containsAll(input));
```

**output**

```
[s, c, a, r, y, w, o, m, b, a, t]
[s, c, a, r, y, w, o, m, b, a, t]
true
[s, c, a, r, y, w, o, m, b, a, t]
[s, c, a, r, y, w, o, m, b, a, t, Z]
false
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to convert the char array to a set and test if any chars in your string contain any character that is not in the array:

```
import com.google.common.primitives.Chars;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

public class Main {

    static char[] f = {'q','w','e','r','t','y','u','i','o','p'};
    static char[] s = {'a','s','d','f','g','h','j','k','l'};
    static char[] t = {'z','x','c','v','b','n','m'};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int count = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            String str = sc.nextLine();
            if(containsOnly(str, f)) count++;
        }
    }

    private static boolean containsOnly(String stringToSearch, char[] theOnlyChars) {

        Set<Character> collect = new HashSet<>(Chars.asList(theOnlyChars));

        for (int i = 0; i < stringToSearch.length(); i++) {
            char c = stringToSearch.charAt(i);
            if (!collect.contains(c)) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
static Pattern f = toPattern(new char[]{'q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't', 'y', 'u', 'i', 'o', 'p'});
static Pattern s = toPattern(new char[]{'a', 's', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l'});
static Pattern t = toPattern(new char[]{'z', 'x', 'c', 'v', 'b', 'n', 'm','\n'});

private static Pattern toPattern(char[] arr) {
    return Pattern.compile(String.format("[%s]*", new String(arr)), Pattern.MULTILINE);
}

private static boolean checkIfStringContainsLettersFromArray(String str, Pattern whitelist) {
    return whitelist.matcher(str).matches();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(checkIfStringContainsLettersFromArray("zxzxzxzxcvbnmxzxz", t)); //true
    System.out.println(checkIfStringContainsLettersFromArray("zxzxzxzxa ", t)); //false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the java Arrays package, simply check whether the character is in the f char array or not. If at least 1 character in the string is not available in the f char array, your program will stop processing the current string and move on to the next.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
static char[] f = {'q','w','e','r','t','y','u','i','o','p'};
static char[] s = {'a','s','d','f','g','h','j','k','l'};
static char[] t = {'z','x','c','v','b','n','m'};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        String str = sc.nextLine();
        char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
        int j = 0;
        for(; j < chars.length; j++){
           if(!Arrays.asList(f).contains(chars[j])){
               break;
           }
        }
        if(j == chars.length){
            count++;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If its the case , you check each character of String against each character of char array, but that would take 2 passes .
If you want more efficient, put all elements in a char array in a Set, its constant time to check a char in that, so only one pass of String is required, like this:

```
public class Main {

    static char[] f = {'q','w','e','r','t','y','u','i','o','p'};
    static char[] s = {'a','s','d','f','g','h','j','k','l'};
    static char[] t = {'z','x','c','v','b','n','m'};
    //showing one example
    HashSet<Character> fs = new HashSet();
    fs.addAll(f);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int count = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            String str = sc.nextLine();
            int flag = 0;
            for (int l =0;l<str.length();l++){
                if(fs.contains(str.charAt(l)) == false){ flag = 1; break;   }
            }
            if (flag == 0){count++}
            //if(string only contains letters from array f) count++;
        }
    }
}
```